# Talend regex for comparing two tables

Tags: sql, regex, join, talend, greenplum

I am a little new to Talend and looking for a way to do a gpdb join using talend. Is there a way to use regex on talend job where 2 tables are joined by comparing two strings?

```
select col1 from tableA
join on
col2 from tableB
on 
string_match(tableA.col1, '.*', 1) = string_match(tableB.colB, '^([^.]+){1}', 1)
WHERE 
<some conditions>;
```

I have tried using tExtractRegex but need some help with how to get a join to do a string match. Can anyone help me out?

Thanks!

Comment: Didn't understand your question. Do you mean to use a regex on the sql string or to use a regex on the talend component? If you want to use a regex on the sql string, then you have to search for regex on your db engine, however if you want to use regex on talend component, then it is just java code, so you can use `.matches(...)`

Comment: I want to use regex on the talend component. I have put in tMap component, but I am stumbling on the java code

Comment: maybe you can add a screenshot of what you want and circle what you need.

Comment: Could you explain and [edit] your question with an example on what are the rules for matching? How do the tables look like?

Answer (score 0):

What you can do with Talend is :

1- Any java expression in the join expression box in the `Tmap`, unfortunatly `Pattern` class of java cannot be used in one instruction but maybe there another way.

2- Generate new filds using `tJavaRow` or `tJavaFlex` and perform any java code that can extract regex match like `Pattern` an `Matcher`, then make a simple join using the new generated fields.